# Xlookup macro falling to aggregate data or taking to long

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a Xlookup macro with filtered data. The issues is when it fills down the data takes a really long time to aggregate and it eventually crashes. I have however noticed that when i escape the macro 1 minute in the data actually shows up. I wondering how i can get the data to aggregate without the time lag or having to push escape.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim MyPath As String
MyPath = "F:\VMWare\supplementalfiles"

Dim LatestFile As String
LatestFile = Most_Recently_Modified_ExcelFile_In_This_Folder(MyPath, "xls")
Dim sFormula As String



' Create formula string
sFormula = "=XLOOKUP(RC[-3],'[" & LatestFile & "]Cos'!C3,'[" & LatestFile & "]Cos'!C4,0)"
' Print formula string to immediate window (Ctrl+G) if window is not visible
Debug.Print sFormula

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="0"
ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = sFormula



''new filter



End Sub

Function Most_Recently_Modified_ExcelFile_In_This_Folder(folderPath As String, fileExtension As String)
fileExtension = Replace(fileExtension, ".", "")
If Right(folderPath, 1) = "\" Then folderPath = Left(folderPath, Len(folderPath))
Dim xFolder, xFile, fileName As String, counter As Integer, latestDate As Date
counter = 0
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set xFolder = .GetFolder(folderPath)
   For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
       If Mid(xFile.Name, InStrRev(xFile.Name, ".") + 1, 3) = fileExtension Then
           If counter = 0 Then
               fileName = xFile.Name
               latestDate = xFile.DateLastModified
               counter = 1
           Else
               If xFile.DateLastModified > latestDate Then
                   latestDate = xFile.DateLastModified
                   fileName = xFile.Name
               End If
           End If
       End If
   Next xFile
End With
Most_Recently_Modified_ExcelFile_In_This_Folder = fileName
End Function
```

Comment: Whole bunch of assumptions need to be made on our part... what's your average data size?  Are there any change events going on (are you disabling events when you run)?  Are you able to change from `XLookUp` to functions or loops?  Hopefully answers to those questions can help provide more context to resolving your issue(s).

Comment: @Cyril the data set from the active sheet is about 150k the sheet that is being used for the xlookup has 6 tabs 2 with about a million 4 with 100k the tab I'm using has 100k. I'm not sure what u mean by events so likely I'm not disabling any events. The only other way would be a V lookup.

Comment: As your code executes, calculations are continually performed, events are triggered, and lots of background activities can occur.  A way to help optimize code is to prevent those from occurring whilst your code finishes, then turn all of that back on.  I'll give a quick example of a subroutine with input that may help to further visualize.

Answer (score 1):

Quick example to help visualize toggle some background activities to support script affecting significant amounts of data:

```
Private Sub toggleApplicationActivities(valas boolean)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = val
        .EnableEvents = val
        If val = false then
            .Calculation = xlManual
        Else
            .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub CodeToExecute()
    toggleApplicationActivities False
    'Do something
    toggleApplicationActivities True
End Sub
```

Comment: Should my code then be inserted inside "do something" or how should i implement the code above ?

Comment: @Alvaroromero Yes.